# how to use spring cloud encrypt RSA Key Manager

Tags: spring, encryption, cloud, rsa

i want to implement spring cloud encrypt RSA key manager like below :

**info:     ar:'{cipher}2253c8971092fdbdc9f0b8448ed760ff6790360a566e382e24925109e1b7bdc1'**

i add the classPath:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and install JCE8 in right place.

in my bootstrap.yml :

encrypt:
        key-store:

```
       location: classpath:microserver.jks
       password: ${KEYSTORE_PASSWORD:jsk8iiu2e}
       alias:  serverconfig
```

My question is :

1. look like above "{cipher}2253.." for example ,if i want to
           encrypt my     password "123456", and the target looks like
           "{cipher}encrypted password" , how to implemented "123456" to "{cipher}encrypted password "?
2. if the encrypted "{cipher}encrypted password"  and the above
   "entrypt
       key-store " microserver.jks had set . i want  to know what
           is the 'key' to decrypt and how to implement ?

who can help me ? thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> look like above "{cipher}2253.." for example ,if i want to encrypt my
>   password "123456", and the target looks like "{cipher}encrypted
>   password" , how to implemented "123456" to "{cipher}encrypted password
>   "?

Config server exposes `/encrypt` and `/decrypt` endpoints, which you can use them for encrypting a clear text or decrypting a cipher text. For example:

```
curl localhost:8888/encrypt -d clear_text
```

This will return the encrypted form of `clear_text`

> if the encrypted
>   "{cipher}encrypted password" and the above "entrypt key-store "
>   microserver.jks had set . i want to know what is the 'key' to decrypt
>   and how to implement ?

Just call the `/decrypt` endpoint like following:

```
curl localhost:8888/decrypt -d cipher_text
```

Comment: I follow yours:
call  /encrypt -d text
result is : "AQAK9ZZkY..."
curl /decrypt -d cipher_text
result is-- the original "text"
it works ! 
but, run  config-server ,it do not .
in bootstrap.yml :
info: '{cipher}AQAK9ZZkY...'

  key-store:
    location: classpath:server.jks
    password: jskk
    alias:  server
when run config-server  , console  errors :
Cannot decrypt: key=info No decryption for FailsafeTextEncryptor. Did you configure the keystore correctly?
but I do not know how to check the keystore's configuration !